# How to attend for the event quests?

Tags: monster-hunter-world

From my Guildcard when I view it and in the log in screen it says I am hunter level 5.
I have 4 pending Event quests that require me to be at least level 5.
Anyways, when I try to post them it tells me that my level isn't high enough.

Is this a bug, or are this 2 diferent kinds of Hunter level it is refering to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

5* quests require you to be Hunter Rank 8 or higher in order to join. You can see this on the right side of the screen when selecting a quest, under "Conditions".